# What is number 1262304000000 in flot charts?

Tags: charts, flot

I am newbie in flot charts, i don't know what is the number 1262304000000, 1264982400000, 1267401600000,... meaning.

```
var d1 = [[1262304000000, 6], [1264982400000, 2057], [1267401600000, 2043], [1270080000000, 2198], [1272672000000, 2660], [1275350400000, 1826], [1277942400000, 1302], [1280620800000, 2237], [1283299200000, 2004], [1285891200000, 2144], [1288569600000, 1577], [1291161600000, 1295]];
```

Thank you very much

Comment: That, as the tag [tag:flot] description points out, is [in the documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three first numbers is the unix-date of 1 jan 2010, 1. feb 2010, 1. mar 2010.

The unit is milliseconds since 1/1/1970

You can try at http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm and delete the last three zeroes, as this site counts in seconds, not milliseconds.